# How can we express Electric field in electrodynamic in term of scalar and vector potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

How can we Express electric field in electrodynamic in term of scalar and vector potential ?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_four-potential)

Answer (score 0):

In electrodynamics we can write: $$\vec{E} = -\nabla V - \frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}$$